# No route matches {} in mailer from Rails upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Anybody know what to do about "No route matches {}"? I'm upgrading an application from Rails 3 to 4.

```
(rdb:1) Rails.application.routes.default_url_options
{:host=>"localhost"}

(rdb:1) inbox_conversation_url(@conversation)
"http://localhost/inbox/conversations/1"

(rdb:1) link_to inbox_conversation_url(@conversation)
*** ActionController::UrlGenerationError Exception: No route matches {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First option of a link to is the label/text. Second option is the url. I think it's because you're not passing anything to argument 2.

```
link_to 'Conversation', inbox_conversation_url(@conversation)
```

Comment: D'oh! My guess is Rails 3 worked with only one argument through a "bug", since you *can* pass a block to it.